# Why does the unicode allows symbols to go beyond the frame

Tags: text, unicode, special-characters

For example, we have such Javanese symbols (꧁,꧅, ꧂ and a few other):

> test
>   **꧅**
> test

which are touching the next line and go beyond the symbol frame. Unlike the Zalgo characters, which consists of symbol and a lot of combined diacritics, our simbols are single ones.
My question is: why is it so, why unicode allows single simbols to do that and is there a list of such symbols (or is it a special property responsible for this).

Comment: Unicode does not prescribe rendering. This behaviour is the responsibility of the font and the text display engine.

Comment: could you please provide more examples of such symbols and explain the environment you are observing them in?